# How to e.preventDefault() when clicking on Update in Gutenberg, WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

How to `e.preventDefault()` when clicking on `Update` in Gutenberg, WordPress?

What I'm trying to do is check something and if there is any error, I will prevent the update process and show the error.

My code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#editor .editor-post-publish-button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Show Errors...
});
```

However, the `e.preventDefault()` is not preventing the process and the post is getting updated.

Comment: if you are handling gutenberg errors, I am not sure this is the way to go. Your question is quite generic - if you explain a bit more detailed, possibly someone can suggest another way of doing what you need to.

I don't know how the publish button is implemented, but depending on how it is, `preventDefault` might not have any effect, since it's literally here to prevent default actions, and not user added actions.

Comment: @Frizzant Yeah, you are right. I would appreciate it if someone can help me to prevent it from submitting using something other than jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JavaScript, you can use the core [WordPress Block API](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/) to issue error notices if your own validation logic detects any issues and prevent the post from saving if errors are present, eg:

**JavaScript**

```js
// Create error notice
wp.data.dispatch('core/notices').createErrorNotice(
    'A value is required', // Message displayed to User
    {
        id: 'my-field', // Used to remove notice and check if notice is present
        isDismissible: false,
    }
);

// Remove notice
wp.data.dispatch('core/notices').removeNotice('my-field'); // unique id 'my-field'

// Prevent post from saving
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).lockPostSaving( 'my-field' );

// Enable post saving
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).unlockPostSaving( 'my-field' );
```

By using native WordPress API, displaying and styling of the notices is taken care of and keeps the UX consistent. The Documentation also has [an example of preventing a post from publishing](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-notices/#createerrornotice) which may be helpful as well.